# Update UI then add a delay

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm  working on Xamarin forms project Using Visual Studio 2017 .I want to  Update the UI then  add a delay then  navigate to another page . I tried the following code and UI update after the delay then without any delay it navigating to the  next page.

```
private void btnAccept_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        SetSuccess();
    });
}



private void SetSuccess()
{
    this.lblStatus.Text = "Thank you";
    this.imageFinger.Source = "kioskQrCodeSuccess.png";
    this.scanProgressBar.IsVisible = false;
    this.LabelInfo.IsVisible = false;

    Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
    s.Start();
    while (s.Elapsed < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
    {
    }

    s.Stop();

    App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Profile());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try [Device.StartTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.device.starttimer?view=xamarin-forms) instead

```
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), () =>
{
    // Do something

    return false;
}
```

Comment: As a side note, this shouldn't be run in the UI thread, right? Or does it not make a difference?

Answer (score 2):

You can consider using `Task.Delay` in an async event handler.

```cs
private async void btnAccept_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    //On UI Thread
    SetSuccess();

    //Non blocking wait
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

    //Back on UI thread
    App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Profile());
}

private void SetSuccess() {
    this.lblStatus.Text = "Thank you";
    this.imageFinger.Source = "kioskQrCodeSuccess.png";
    this.scanProgressBar.IsVisible = false;
    this.LabelInfo.IsVisible = false;
}
```